# Facebook: collecting the specific posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I have a simple question for Facebook developers. I would like to create website which would collect and embed some specific data from Facebook. For example, let's say I want facebook's posts or images with the most likes on a daily basis. Here's what I think:

Let's say there are **x** pages that I follow on Facebook. So at the beginning of each day or at some point I would like to loop through the posts of these pages and get the most popular posts/images.

Is this possible to embed to website? I am relatively newbie to facebook development.

I look forward to seeing your answers!

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed a specific post with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts. The specific nature of your question is not possible though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought it would be good idea to collect favorite people's posts and display it to them on a single page, all together (like 9gag.com for example). A good idea for increasing the number of visitors for your website ;-)